# how to disable modal bootstrap when click a specific element

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I want disable the modal when click in a td of the table with class 
"buttons-admin" but when click in the others td of the table , enable the modal.

```
        echo "<tbody>";
        echo "<tr title='informacion detallada' class='selector-empleado' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#infodetallada".$fila['rut']."'>";
        echo "<td>".$fila["rut"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$fila["nombre"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$fila["apellido"]."</td>";

        //THIS CLASS "buttons-admin"

        echo "<td class='buttons-admin'><button onClick='window.location=\"modificarempleado.php?rut=".$fila["rut"]."\";'/ title='modificar empleado' class='btn btn-primary btn-admin1'><span class='fa fa-refresh'></span></button>
        <button  onClick='window.location=\"eliminarempleado.php?rut=".$fila["rut"]."\";'/ title='eliminar empleado' class='btn btn-danger btn-admin2'>
        <span class='fa fa-times'></span></button></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</tbody>";
```

Comment: put the `data-toggle='modal' ...` on the td's the not the tr, or do it with js

Comment: use jquery click event on other's td class to show modal use `$(selector).modal('show')`

Comment: thanks friends! I'ts working ;)